# How to change appendix IDs?

Tags: appendices

I'm writing a document in Russian and use the [appendix](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/appendix) package.

Currently, it uses Latin letters A, B, C etc. to identify the individual appendices. I want to change these letters either to Russian ones (A, Б, В etc.) or to numbers.

How can I do this?

**Update 1:**

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,10pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,
normalheadings,DIV=9,twoside=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\linespread{1.05} 

\usepackage{graphicx}

% \usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\newcommand{\q}[1]{>>\textit{#1}<<}

\title{A book title}
\author{My name} 
\date{\today} 


\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Приложения}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Приложения}

\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{...}
\section{...}
TBD
\section{...}
TBD
\section{...}
TBD
\section{...}
TBD

\chapter{...}
\section{...}
TBD
\section{...}
TBD
\section{...}
TBD
\section{...}
TBD

\chapter{...}
TBD

\chapter{...}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item ...
    \item ...
    \item ...
\end{enumerate}

\end{appendices}      

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which language-related packages (`babel`?, `polyglossia`?), if any, do you use?

Comment: @Mico See my update 1.

Comment: Thanks for providing some code that describes your main document setup. However, it doesn't show just how you start the appendix matter, and hence it's not straightforward to provide suggestions on how you you should proceed to change the numbering style of chapters located in the appendix. Maybe this material is in the file `_text.tex`, but without having access to it it's not possible to tell.

Comment: @Mico See update 2.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko I've merged the code so to make a MWE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest workaround is to say

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Asbuk{chapter}}
```

just after the appendix are started.

Here is how to, based on your MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,10pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,
normalheadings,DIV=9,twoside=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}


% \usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Приложения}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Приложения}

\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Asbuk{chapter}}

\chapter{...}
\section{...}
TBD
\section{...}
TBD
\section{...}
TBD
\section{...}
TBD

\chapter{...}
\section{...}
TBD
\section{...}
TBD
\section{...}
TBD
\section{...}
TBD

\chapter{...}
TBD

\chapter{...}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item ...
    \item ...
    \item ...
\end{enumerate}

\end{appendices}      

\end{document}
```

Here's a picture of the second appendix:

[image]

A way to avoid the explicit command after `\begin{appendices}` is to have in the preamble

```
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Приложения}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Приложения}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendices{\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Asbuk{chapter}}}
\makeatother
```

Then just `\begin{appendices}` will do.